# Hacking ATM with its aux port

Tags: analog, frequency, dac, fsk

(I opened a topic about it a few minutes ago but I thought it would be better if I ask my question more properly.)

I wonder if is it possible to hacking an ATM (through it's aux port) with connecting it to a BadUSB with some converters like DACs or FSKs or sending ultrasonic waves and proper electrical signals ?

I scared to ask this question like that, I have no evil thoughts about it. I was just looking for quiet modem and stuff and that thing just stuck on my mind.

Comment: [Buy an ATM and try.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4StcW9OPpPc)

Comment: This is an ethically challenging question considering your lack of explanation for motivation. There are more ethically better things to hack and ask about.

Comment: what is an ATM?

Comment: @jsotola A machine that withdraws cash from your bank account. You put your card in, choose how much cash you want, and it gives you back your card and some cash, and your bank account has less money in it.

Comment: (most people are going to be wondering why I have to describe what an ATM is, but perhaps they are very uncommon in some places)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible. Do you know what the aux port is there for? I assume it's there to give feedback to blind people using the ATM.
If that's the case, the aux port probably is output only and hacking the atm this way would be pretty much like hacking the atm via its display using a video projector.

Comment: Actually there are ATM's with mic for blind people as well (For voice control). So some of them are both output and input.

Comment: That's interesting, but even in that case I doubt that it's possible. It would be a really poor security if you could hack it using the regular input. The analogy in this case would be to hack the atm by using nothing but its public keypad (not a keypad one could plug into the internal computer).